# Acumatica Release action after ARBalance update

Tags: acumatica

I need to get the ARBalance with the latest update after the Release action is run from the Invoice screen (SO303000).
I have tried with the override code for Release action

```
    public delegate IEnumerable ReleaseDelegate(PXAdapter adapter);
    [PXOverride]
    public IEnumerable Release(PXAdapter adapter, ReleaseDelegate baseMethod)
    {
        return baseMethod(adapter);
    }
```

I'm getting the error message:  "Method Void UpdateBaReleaseInvoiceTransactionPostProcessing(PX.Objects.GL.JournalEntry, PX.Objects.AR.ARInvoice, PX.Data.PXResult`6[PX.Objects.AR.ARTran,PX.Objects.AR.ARTax,PX.Objects.TX.Tax,PX.Objects.DR.DRDeferredCode,PX.Objects.SO.SOOrderType,PX.Objects.AR.ARTaxTran], PX.Objects.GL.GLTran, ReleaseInvoiceTransactionPostProcessingDelegate) in graph extension is marked as [PXOverride], but the original method with such name has not been found in PXGraph ".

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve my problem by using the Row Persisted on the Balance on the ARReleaseProcess Graph.